# Why is inverse of orthogonal matrix is its transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

So the question is in the title. It's easy to prove when we know that there are real numbers in it and the dot product is standard. But why this works in the general case - when there are complex numbers inside and the dot product is something else?

Comment: How did you define orthogonal matrix?

Comment: A square matrix with orthonormal basis of $\Bbb{R}^n$ or $\Bbb{C}^n$ inside

Comment: orthonormal with respect to which inner product?

Comment: By the way for complex number $$A^{-1}=A^*.$$

Comment: So, if you calculate $AA^*$, can you 1) View each entry in the product as an inner product of a row/column? 2) show that $AA^*$ is $I$?

Comment: @OfirSchnabel I have inner product defined as a function of  vectors for which the following statements are true: $<x,ay_1+by_2>=a<x,y_1>+b<x,y_2>$ for scalars a,b; $<x,y>=conjugate of <y,x>$ and if $x \neq 0$ then $<x,x> > 0$

Comment: By your definition $R_i\cdot \bar{C_j}=0$ for any $i\neq j$ and if $i=j$ then $R_i\cdot \bar{C_j}=1$ for $R$-rows of $A$ and $C$-columns of $A^t$. Hence $AA^*=I$

Comment: actually it's not: `[[2,0][0,2]]` is orthogonal but its inverse is `[[0.5,0][0,0.5]]`. I think you mean orthonormal

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let $C_i$ the $i^{\text{th}}$ column of the orthogonal matrix $O$ then  we have

$$\langle C_i,C_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$$
and we have 
$$O^T=(C_1\;\cdots\; C_n)^T=(C_1^T\;\cdots\; C_n^T)$$
so we get

$$O^TO=(\langle C_i,C_j\rangle)_{1\le i,j\le n}=I_n$$

Comment: In my humble opinion this is not general enough for OPs question. (I posted an answer and deleted it after I reread the question.) The claim $\langle C_i, C_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$ for an orthogonal matrix is in general not true. (Note OP included "when the dot product is something else.")

Comment: I agree. Doesn't this proof assume that the dot product is $x^Ty$? I asked why is the statement valid in the general case, for example if there are complex numbers inside the matrix the dot product can be defined as $x^Hy$ and then it is not equal $x^Ty$. Am I right?

Comment: With the field of complex numbers, the matrix which you ask about is called unitary matrix not orthogonal matrix and the proof is generally  the same. @qiubit

Comment: Without definitions for the form introduced. Just tautology. What is inside brackets and bra-ket?

Answer (score 6):

A is othogonal means A'A = I. That says that A' is the inverse of A!

Comment: Sorry but my definition of orthogonal matrix is different

Comment: @qiubit : Once you realize that the $i,j$ element of the matrix $A'A$ is the inner product of columns $i$ and $j$ of $A$, you should realize that $A' A=I$ is an equivalent definition of an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Isn't that true ONLY if the dot product is defined as $x^Ty$?

Answer (score 0):

Represent your orthogonal matrix $O$ as element of the [Lie Group of Orthogonal Matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Lie_algebra). You get:

$$O = \exp(\Omega),$$
where $\exp$ means the [matrix exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) and $\Omega$ is an element of the corresponding Lie Algebra, which is skew-symmetric, *i.e.* $\Omega^T = -\Omega$. Now transpose it to get:
$$O^T=\exp(\Omega)^T=\exp(\Omega^T)=\exp(-\Omega),$$
which is the inverse of $O$: 
Since $\Omega$ and $-\Omega$ [commute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices), *i.e.* $[\Omega,-\Omega]_-=0$ we can write $$O^TO=\exp(-\Omega)\exp(\Omega)=\exp(-\Omega+\Omega)=\exp(0)=1$$

Comment: The exponential map isn't surjective onto the full orthogonal group.

Answer (score 0):

ΩT=−Ω. Now transpose it to get:
OT=exp(Ω)T=exp(ΩT)=exp(−Ω),
which is the inverse of O: Since Ω and −Ω commute, i.e. [Ω,−Ω]−=0 we can write
OTO=exp(−Ω)exp(Ω)=exp(−Ω+Ω)=exp(0)+ 0+1 -1 transpose 1+0 +Y -X +0=1

Answer (score 0):

Many have already explained it in a more calculation or geometric centric way. Here is my understanding from a "instinct/fundamental point of view".
Consider we are going to rotate certain vector
$$ V = \begin{bmatrix}i \\j \\k \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
with a rotation (thus orthogonal) matrix
$$ Q = \begin{bmatrix}
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Note the c1, c2 and c3 are column vectors, so the product is:
$$ U = i * c1 + j * c2 + k *c3$$
Right now we want to find an inverse matrix of Q, called M, so that U can turn back to V.
$$ V = M*U = i* M*c1 + j*M*c2 + k* M*c3 = \begin{bmatrix}i \\j \\k \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

What does it mean anyway? remember the transformation is just a change of basis: from one coordinate system to another coordinate system, the c1, c2, and c3 vectors are an orthonormal basis, by using them to make a linear expression they "adapt" our current x, y, z numbers into the new coordinate system. It's just multiplication of constant and vectors then add them up, just like $ U = i * c1 + j * c2 + k *c3$.
But to adapt them backwards (do an inverse), we cannot use an easy linear expression anymore, we have to apply a matrix multiplication.

Now the i, j, k are all just constants, not vectors or element of a vector, that means we must have:
$$ M*c1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \\0 \\ \end{bmatrix},
 M*c2 = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\1 \\0 \\ \end{bmatrix}
M*c3 = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\0 \\1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Let's define
$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}
\cdots & r1 & \cdots \\
\cdots & r2 & \cdots \\
\cdots & r3 & \cdots \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where r1 r2 and r3 are row vectors, combined with the equation above:
$$r1*c1 = 1, r2*c1 = 0, r3*c1=0, r2*c1 = 0, r2*c2 = 1 ...$$
In the end, the only solution of this is:
$$r1 = c1, r2 = c2, r3 = c3$$
where c1, c2, c3 are orthonormal.
That means $M = Q^T$.

So $M = Q^T = Q^-1$