# Understanding why the inverse of an ortogonal matrix is its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I have seen this question asked many times here for example:
[Why is inverse of orthogonal matrix is its transpose?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097422/why-is-inverse-of-orthogonal-matrix-is-its-transpose)

I understand how the answers on that question proves it.

But I want to understand it from the approach of computing the inverse

If we look at tutorials on computing the inverse.
It says to swap `a` and `d` in the diagonal.
for example in this tutorial:
https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse.html

it seems to me that this wouldn't give the transpose because `a` and `d` should stay in the same place for the transpose.

Comment: What is your definition of "orthogonal" matrix?  This matters.

Comment: To be precise, you're thinking only about the $2\times 2$ case. Do you know what $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrices look like (other than just saying the definition)?

Comment: Swapping $a$ and $d$ seems counterintuitive, but it's fine. Think about how we can find vectors orthogonal to a vector $(a, b)$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$. The standard way is to swap $a$ and $b$, negating one, so $(b, -a)$ or $(-b, a)$. In fact, these are the only two such vectors with the same length as $(a, b)$. So, our orthonormal bases must be of the form $(a, b), (b, -a)$, or $(a, b), (-b, a)$. Putting these as columns in a matrix (an orthogonal $2 \times 2$ matrix) means that the diagonal entries ($a$ and $d$) are either equal or are negatives of each other!